# What's the correct way to cite a paper cited by another paper?

Tags: citations

The example is when you might be reading a certain paper, and the authors refer to another paper. You can't get that other paper as it's unpublished, or it's in a language that you can't read, or maybe something else.

My guess is:

> Featherstone et al 1900 (in Thomas and Cullen 2002).

And how is it to be handled in the bibliography?

Comment: I think the answer would depend on *why* you want to cite Featherstone.  Obviously it isn't because of the important things you learned from reading it!

Comment: Just to make this very specific situation clear (which I didn't want to do, as it works better for all if it's just a little general): I cannot obtain the original paper as our libraries cannot get it (perhaps if I had unlimited time and so on I could find it?). The paper I do have sufficiently details the data from the secondary source, and those data are all I need. Just data, in a table, very simple. There's a lot of hand-wringing going on here, and some insinuations about my character, but just have a little generosity of spirit for and some faith in your fellow humans.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/12391/64

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In APA style, you can write, (e.g., [see this APA tutorial](http://www.lib.monash.edu.au/tutorials/citing/apa.html))

> Featherstone et al 1900 (as cited in Thomas and Cullen 2002)

Of course, in general you should try your best to read the original and cite the original directly.

Someone in the comments asked:

> "In such case do I need to list original paper also in reference section or only the recent one I am referring to?"

The reference to the original article is the more important reference to include, but you should include both in your reference list.

Comment: Thanks. That also tells me that the term is 'secondary source'. Another nice tool I've just found is this one: http://www.lib.unimelb.edu.au/recite/index.html

Comment: I always interpret this to mean that Thomas and Cullen (2002) said something about Featherstone et al (1900) that is not obvious and often contentious or wrong.

Comment: I associate it most with student lab reports.

Comment: In such case do I need to list original paper also in reference section or only the recent one I am referring to?

Answer (score 3):

The following is with regards to Chicago Style as of 11/25/2018
14.260: Citations taken from secondary sources 
Chapter Contents / Special Types of References / Citations Taken from Secondary Sources 
To cite a source from a secondary source (“quoted in . . .”) is generally to be discouraged, since authors are expected to have examined the works they cite. If an original source is unavailable, however, both the original and the secondary source must be listed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a quote from author A that author B is citing, you would go ahead and use the quote from author A and cite it like this:

> Blah blah, blahblahblah, blah blah blah-blah blah (qtd. in Author B 65).

Answer (score -3):

If you cannot get that paper, you **should not** cite it.

What is a citation? The word *citation* comes from Latin verb *cio* (past participle: *citum*) that means *to call somebody*, *to invite somebody*, or preferably **to demand someone to give his own testimony**.

So, in your case, if you would like to cite that paper, that means that you invite that paper to give its own testimony. But **if it's not available**, how could it do it?

Simply, **it can't**.

Comment: No, you have a moral obligation to cite it regardless (and the etymology is completely irrelevant).  Deliberately not citing a relevant paper because you couldn't track down a copy is a potentially career-destroying ethical mistake.  It's a matter of credit and historical information, not just ease of availability.  (Of course, if you don't have access yourself you need to trust someone else as to what is in there, and you should indicate that, but it's not a reason to erase someone from history.)

Comment: This is plainly wrong: unfortunately, sometimes author A refers to private communication with B, so there is no other way fo you to cite B then by an indirect reference.

Comment: The origins of the word citation are not of great consequence.  The main point of citation is that a person can trace back a sequence of credible arguments.  It is important to cite both the original content and the commenter's paper as sources of this information.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician I think the obligation is to get the source (and have it translated if necessary) and then decide if you should cite it. Citing a source without having the source is unethical.

Comment: @Anonymous Mathematician It's completely the contrary: you have a moral obligation not to cite it, because, since you did not read it, you cannot know what it actually contains. And if you do not know what it effectively contains, you will probably give a wrong meaning to its citation. In addition, deliberately citing a paper also if you couldn't track down a copy is a potentially career-destroying ethical mistake: an expert (who READ the paper) could easily find many errors in your paper and in the meaning you gave to the article citation.

Comment: Citing something has nothing to do with reading or not reading it.  It means having it appear in your bibliography and get referred to in your text.  You're right that there are issues in how you refer to it: you have a scholarly obligation to say correct things about it, and an ethical obligation not to be sloppy or misleading.  Pretending to have read something you haven't is indeed ethically problematic, but that's a matter of how you cite it, not whether you cite it.  Omitting the citation entirely is tantamount to pretending you aren't aware of the paper.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician: "Citing something has nothing to do with reading or not reading it": see [Simkin & Roychowdhury 2003](http://www.complex-systems.com/pdf/14-3-5.pdf)...

Comment: It's true that a lot of partially false sentences have been moving from citation to citation without people having read the original paper (similar to the broken telephone game - if that's international). So, I would agree that you should read the papers that you cite, at least the part that you are referring to. If the original paper is not available despite your efforts, I would rather not cite it, rather than add something potentially wrong. A secondary citation might sort this, as it moves the responsibility to others, but it could still be adding accidental lies in our writings.

Comment: Downvoted, in complete agreement with @AnonymousMathematician.  Yes, ideally you should read every source you cite, but in the absence of perfection, it is important to be clear.  Secondary citations (“...as cited in...”) allow proper allocation of credit _to the best of the author’s knowledge_ while acknowledging that the author has not read (ideally, _could_ not read) the original source.

Comment: Just advised someone who is citing a paper through another because the original is in Spanish, and the secondary source cites it in English translation. Sometimes important works are not available, and yet very useful to research. After all, we cite Euclid, Aristotle, even though we've not read their original publication.