# How to reference to a statement that itself is referenced by a paper other than original paper?

Tags: publications, citations, writing

When I read a statement in a paper that is itself derived from another paper, how should I reference it when I use it in my own article? Should I reference the original article or the second article, or both?

Answer (score 0):

You should *read* the original article and afterwards cite it. Don't omit the "read"-step since the secondary source might have introduced an error.

BTW: You should read all the related posts, e.g. [How to reference studies mentioned in a paper without having to read the original papers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12391/how-to-reference-studies-mentioned-in-a-paper-without-having-to-read-the-origina?rq=1)